# why I can not create tablespace in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have installed centos 6.3 On vmware, and the postgresql is self-contained, the Version is PostgreSQL 8.4.13 on i386-redhat-linux-gnu.

I want to create a tablespace with command like This:
**create tablespace foo LOCATION '/usr/foo1';**

But I am getting Error like this:
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/tmp/foo1": Permission denied

Then I checked the /tmp/foo1's owner and the owner is indeed postgres,
So I confused about this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you also need to own the parent directory. But is it /tmp/foo1 or /usr/foo1 (both of which are rather unorthodox locations)?

Comment: Also, be sure you are the postgres user when you issue the command.

Comment: It does not work,but when I specify the folder /var/lib/pgsql/data/xx Then I can create a tablespace, I don't konw why?

Answer (score 0):

things I would check:

1. Usually /tmp should have open permissions.  However if they are closed off...
2. What filesystem is /tmp on?  Does it support file permissions?
3. What are the appropriate filesystem mounting options or such for /tmp?  Could these interfere?